# How to enable cookiemiddleware in scrapy in python

Tags: python, scrapy

IN their documentation here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#cookies-mw

They told to enable the cookie middle , but i am not able to find how to do that and which file to edit for that. Can anyone tell me how can i do that

Comment: This is a good question, I find the Scrapy middleware documentation to be poorly explained.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**update** it would appear cookies are in the middleware by default, so just `COOKIES_ENABLED = True` should be sufficient. You only need the below if the middleware is not part of the defaults...

From what I can tell from doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html you add
`'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.cookies.CookiesMiddleware'` to DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARE with a relevant ordering:

> To activate a downloader middleware component, add it to the
>   DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES setting, which is a dict whose keys are the
>   middleware class paths and their values are the middleware orders.

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middlewares.CustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.cookies.CookiesMiddleware': 700 # <-
}
```

The 700 comes from the default `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES_BASE` at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#built-in-downloader-middleware-reference
Then put `COOKIES_ENABLED = True` (and optionally `COOKIES_DEBUG = True`) with the rest of your settings.

Answer (score 3):

Just put:

```
COOKIES_DEBUG = True
```

in `my-project/my-spider/spiders/settings.py`