# HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Tags: python, scrapy

I need crawl a site with cookie using Scrapy,but returns error

code here

```
class XueqiuSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "xueqiu"
    start_urls = ["https://xueqiu.com/stock/f10/finmainindex.json?symbol=SZ000001&page=1&size=1"]
    delimiter = ','
    quotechar = '"'
    headers = ["symbol","date","open","high","low","close","volume"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for i,url in enumerate(self.start_urls):
            print(url)
            yield Request(url,cookies={'aliyungf_tc':'AQAAANiAQ3xQ/QAAZ0J2fRFnxcJufEzG'},callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print response
```

errors show

```
********Current UserAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 2268.111.0) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11************
2017-03-02 18:56:02 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Sending cookies to: <GET https://xueqiu.com/stock/f10/finmainindex.json?symbol=SZ000001&page=1&size=1>
Cookie: aliyungf_tc=AQAAANiAQ3xQ/QAAZ0J2fRFnxcJufEzG; aliyungf_tc=AQAAAM/c+1g5vAMAZ0J2fbusPyBy7jb1

2017-03-02 18:56:02 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET https://xueqiu.com/stock/f10/finmainindex.json?symbol=SZ000001&page=1&size=1> (referer: None)
2017-03-02 18:56:02 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://xueqiu.com/stock/f10/finmainindex.json?symbol=SZ000001&page=1&size=1>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Comment: Where from you are trying to scrape data? I know its xueqiu.com website but which part? Can you post the actual link? I am 100% sure you are missing some additional request headers that is why you are getting 400 error.

Comment: the link here,https://xueqiu.com/stock/f10/finmainindex.json?symbol=SZ000001&page=1&size=1

Comment: No I am not asking about that URL ... ... :( Ok anyways, where did you get the URL from? Is this an AJAX URL? or what?

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in [doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html), according to the HTTP standard, successful responses are those whose status codes are in the **200-300** range.

If you still want to process response codes outside that range, you can specify which response codes the spider is able to handle using the handle_httpstatus_list spider attribute or `HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES` setting.

So you should add it in your code

```
class XueqiuSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [400]
```

Comment: error still there,DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET https://xueqiu.com/stock/f10/finmainindex.json?symbol=SZ000001&page=1&size=1> (referer: None)

Comment: @Flasking it's not an error, it's a debug message that says that the page was crawled successfully.

Comment: @Flasking are you sure that middleware is enabled?

Comment: @parik yes,as this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488106/how-to-enable-cookiemiddleware-in-scrapy-in-python said ,have enabled CookiesMiddleware